# Need Post Expiry Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I am really proud to be a part of this platform. The platform really helps me a lot when I faces any issue. I have a Job Portal blogger website. I want to show expiry date on post cards which are shown on homepage. I already asked this question to a blogger theme developer and he says me that it is not possible. If this was not possible then how Post labels, post published date, post author show on post cards. Please help me out regarding this issue.

Why I need this? This function helps the viewers to decide which post should they visit or not. Please create a post expiry date for blogger posts which shows on post cards.

Take a look my site and create this function with html or css or javascript.
https://www.pkjob.site/

Comment: how are you defining that date another than hard coding into the post? if its returned you can set it into a *card* via a bit of dom manipulation if it's not then your out of luck (which you need alot of using blogger)

Comment: I do not have any knowledge to create this function in blogger that's why I am sharing my issue with this platform geniusesl